# Laravel eloquent relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Table 1

```
id user_id disbursed_id
1     1       1
2     1       2
3     2       3
4     2       4
```

Table 2

```
id user_id disbursed_id data
1    1         1        data 1
2    1         2        data 2
```

I am trying to make relation for **disbursed_id** of particular **user_id**

Comment: what table 1 for and what table 2 for..? they had similar fields..  also what relationship is this? one-to-many or many-to-many looks like many-to-many..? you can see the example on [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) on how to setup many-to-many relationship..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new migration to add the foreign key. For example

```
$table->foreign('disbursed_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users');
```

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) on adding foreign key constraints on Laravel.